# Slice contour graphic at given level

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following  function (`z`) that should output a graphic which if sliced at `f(x,y) = 0.001` the result image should be a message.

I wrote this code but I`m unable to slice it right

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1.5:0.3:1.5,-2.5:0.5:2.5) ;
z=exp(-4*x.^2-2*y.^2)*cos(8*x)+exp(-3*((2*x+1)/2).^2-6*y.^2);           
% meshc (x,y,z, [0.001 0.001]);

meshc (x,y,z);
```

What did i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely looking for the [`countour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) function instead of [`meshc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshc.html). `meshc` plots a contour plot under a mesh plot, but you don't need a mesh plot to view the message. In fact, the `countour` docs show an [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html#bt2l3yh) of how to only plot a specific level:

```
contour(x, y, z, [0.001 0.001])
```

I also suspect that your function is not defined correctly. `exp(...) * cos(...)` should probably read `exp(...) .* cos(...)`:

[image]

The poor granularity leads me to believe that the sample spacing should be decreased (i.e., the grid should be made finer):

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1.5:0.003:1.5,-2.5:0.005:2.5);
```

[image]

Contouring the original function with the finer spacing also shows why I think `*` should probably be `.*` in the expression:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1.5:0.003:1.5,-2.5:0.005:2.5);
z=exp(-4*x.^2-2*y.^2)*cos(8*x)+exp(-3*((2*x+1)/2).^2-6*y.^2);
contour(x, y, z, [0.001 0.001])
```

[image]

Unless the message is a count of sausage shapes, I think that the `.*` version is more likely to contain useful information (looks like HI).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) rather than `meshc` to plot the intersection of your mesh with `0.001` so that you can specify exactly at what value you'd like to compute the contour.

```
contour(x, y, z, [0.001 0.001]);
```

If you *do* want to use `meshc`, you can use the output which contains a handle to the contour plot to set the `LevelList` property to your desired value

```
h = meshc(x, y, z);
set(findobj(h, 'type', 'contour'), 'LevelList', [0.001 0.001])
```

As far as getting an intelligible message out, I guess intelligent is in the eye of the beholder

[image]